# Android Quiz Application with local SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I m developing an Android quiz application. I want to store the questions and other datas in local SQLite database.

**How can i manage this ?**

**Especially when i want to add some questions (records to the database), what should i do ?**

**How can i make the device that has my published application to get my new questions into its local SQLite database ?**

I know something about application versioning in Android (with version code and version name) and also know about SQLite usage in Android (database version and database upgrade) but i only want to change/extend the records of the database not the structure or schema.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to communicate new questions/answers to the device with your app on it. Possibilities I can think of off the top of my head:

1. Post an update to the Play Store. In the update, increase the database version number and in onUpgrade just do some SQL `INSERT` statements.
2. Create a server that hosts your questions and answers. Have the app call a REST endpoint on your server periodically (maybe once a day). If you have new questions, the server can send them in the response and the device can insert them into the database.

Comment: Thank you. The second one seems more convenient. Do you offer to check if any new questions are available in my database in application's first pages's onCreate method ? 

So should i check if there is anything new on startup every time the user open the app (if they have internet connection) ?

Comment: It's really up to you. You could even do both (startup and periodic).